# jquery checkbox checked count issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table that looks like this: http://jsfiddle.net/8SEz2/4/

```
Branch    StSeq#   Inv#  Invoice Date    Payable Amount     Pay?
Branch1     2       A2   11/11/2011        49,500.00       checkbox(unchecked)
Branch1     3       A3   11/11/2011        12,221.55       checkbox(checked)
Branch3     4       B1   11/11/2011        12,220.56       checkbox(unchecked)
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is when a row checkbox state is changed I need to count the number of checkboxes that are also checked that share the same branch name.

Ex. If I click on the first checkbox, (Branch1) I should get a popup with the branch checked count and in this case, it should be 2.

This is my jquery:

```
//Please refer to the jsFiddle for the class names
//used to track checked branches
$('input.payMe').change(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    //cm enable
    var branchName = $(this).parent().prevAll("td.invoiceBranch").html().trim();
    var branchCount = 0;
    $('td.invoiceBranch').each(function(index) {
        if ($(this).html().trim() == branchName) {
            branchCount++;
        }
    });
        alert(branchCount);
    }
    else {
    //cm disable
        var branchName = $(this).parent().prevAll("td.invoiceBranch").html().trim();
        var branchCount = 0;
        $('td.invoiceBranch').each(function (index) {
            if ($(this).html().trim() == branchName) {
                //Needs to select the checkbox to get checked state.
                //Not sure if this is correct
                var inputHTML = $(this).nextAll("td.paymentCheckBox").first();
                if($(inputHTML).is(":checked")) {
                    branchCount++;
                }
            }
        });      
        alert(branchCount);
    }
});
```

Any ideas? I've been stumped for 2 days. Thanks!

Comment: Why not code the branchname as part of the checkbox ID or name ??

Comment: I considered that, but it's not what I need. I have another table in that page that has it's rows disabled if the number of branched checked is 0. So if 1 out of two checkboxes of Branch1 is selected, my other table's rows get enabled, if it's zero, it needs to be disabled again. That's why I need the total checked count.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should apply a tag for each checkbox with the name of branch

```
<input type="checkbox" class="payMe" branch="Branch1" ... />
```

Then the function should roughly be like

```
$(':checkbox.payMe').change(function() {
  alert($(':checkbox.payMe[branch="' + $(this).attr('branch') + '"]:checked').length);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/8SEz2/2/

I added the attribute data-branch to the checkboxes

and here his the js:

```
$(".payMe").change(function(){
    var branch = $(this).attr('data-branch');        
    alert( $("input[data-branch='" + branch + "']:checked").length );
});
```